# In sunmi_printer_plus, printRow not working properly on Thai language

Tags: flutter, thermal-printer

I'm using this package [sunmi_printer_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sunmi_printer_plus/example).

Here my code

```
await SunmiPrinter.bindingPrinter();
await SunmiPrinter.initPrinter();
await SunmiPrinter.startTransactionPrint(true);
await SunmiPrinter.printText(
  restaurant.title,
  style: SunmiStyle(
    align: SunmiPrintAlign.CENTER,
  ),
);
await SunmiPrinter.lineWrap(1);
await SunmiPrinter.printText(
  'ใบเสร็จ',
  style: SunmiStyle(
    align: SunmiPrintAlign.CENTER,
  ),
);
await SunmiPrinter.line();
await SunmiPrinter.printRow(cols: [
  ColumnMaker(text: 'NO:', width: 10, align: SunmiPrintAlign.LEFT),
  ColumnMaker(text: order.id, width: 20, align: SunmiPrintAlign.RIGHT),
]);
await SunmiPrinter.printRow(cols: [
  ColumnMaker(text: 'Time:', width: 10, align: SunmiPrintAlign.LEFT),
  ColumnMaker(
      text: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
          .format(order.paidTime ?? DateTime.now()),
      width: 20,
      align: SunmiPrintAlign.RIGHT),
]);
await SunmiPrinter.line();
await SunmiPrinter.bold();
await SunmiPrinter.printRow(cols: [
  ColumnMaker(text: 'Menu', width: 15, align: SunmiPrintAlign.LEFT),
  ColumnMaker(text: 'Price', width: 15, align: SunmiPrintAlign.RIGHT),
]);
await SunmiPrinter.resetBold();
for (var item in order.cart.items) {
  await SunmiPrinter.printRow(cols: [
    ColumnMaker(
        text: '${item.amount} x ${item.product.title}',
        width: 20,
        align: SunmiPrintAlign.LEFT),
    ColumnMaker(
        text: item.totalPrice.toString(),
        width: 10,
        align: SunmiPrintAlign.RIGHT),
  ]);
}
await SunmiPrinter.line();
await SunmiPrinter.printRow(cols: [
  ColumnMaker(text: 'Total', width: 10, align: SunmiPrintAlign.LEFT),
  ColumnMaker(
      text: '฿${order.cart.totalPrice}',
      width: 20,
      align: SunmiPrintAlign.RIGHT),
]);
await SunmiPrinter.lineWrap(1);
await SunmiPrinter.printText(
  'ขอบคุณที่มาอุดหนุนค่ะ',
  style: SunmiStyle(
    align: SunmiPrintAlign.CENTER,
    fontSize: SunmiFontSize.SM,
  ),
);
await SunmiPrinter.printText(
  'Powered by Dr.Dish',
  style: SunmiStyle(
    align: SunmiPrintAlign.CENTER,
    fontSize: SunmiFontSize.SM,
  ),
);
await SunmiPrinter.lineWrap(3);
await SunmiPrinter.exitTransactionPrint(true);
```

Here result

[image]

as you can see, the character is stack on each other on lines that use `printRow`. (`printText` working fine)

and it working fine when I change to English.

[image]

What do I miss or this is a bug? I tried to change column size and word length, but still not working.

Comment: The Thai code table of ESC/POS printer may not follow the international standards. It may also be in a proprietary format, depending on the printer vendor and model. In that case the library will not support that printer. Please check that information. [ESC t](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32), [Page 20 \[Thai Character Code 42\]](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_charcode_en/index.php?content_id=30)

Comment: @kunif Can you suggest me how to fix or work around this?

Comment: Please get the Thai code table information from your printer vendor. Then you could ask the library's author to support that printer, or you could get the library's source code and customize it yourself.

Comment: @kunif I'm using Sunmi V2 pro, and I pretty sure it support Thai language. I can also print receipt in Thai using application loyverse, but I want to print through my app.

Comment: The material published on these pages does not appear to support Thai code tables. [V2 PRO](https://developer.sunmi.com/docs/en-US/ceghjk502/czceghjk502), [Inbuilt Non-detachable Printers Documentation](https://developer.sunmi.com/docs/en-US/xeghjk491/ciqeghjk513), [ESC&POS commands document](https://ota.cdn.sunmi.com/DOC/resource/re_en/ESC-POS%20Command%20set.docx) If it's actually supported and just unpublished, please ask the vendor. If it really isn't supported, an alternative would be to create everything as a bitmap image and print it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can print it by convert it to image then it to printing**

```
//Set prepare text as Paragraph

var builder = ParagraphBuilder(
  ParagraphStyle(
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
      fontSize: 28,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      maxLines: 10),
);

// Set text color to black
builder.pushStyle(ui.TextStyle(color: ui.Color(0xFF000000))); // Black color
builder.addText(text ?? '');
builder.pop();

Paragraph paragraph = builder.build();
paragraph.layout(const ParagraphConstraints(width: 580));

final recorder = PictureRecorder();
var canvas = Canvas(recorder);
double textHeight = paragraph.height + 5;

// Draw a white background
canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 580, textHeight), Paint()..color = Colors.white);

canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, Offset.zero);

final picture = recorder.endRecording();
var res = await picture.toImage(580, textHeight.toInt());
ByteData? data = await res.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
if (data != null) {
  final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
 await SunmiPrinter.printImage(bytes)

}
```